# Sales of two different weeks without summing them in one single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2022

I am trying to get the sales of a week formatted by days of the week, the problem is that my query behaves like a normal `Sum()`, ignoring sales from different weeks of the same days. In the example database I am inserting two different sales on two different weeks and the same day of the week resulting in a single row of 38.92, instead of two rows with the sales according to that day of the week.

This is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN weekdays = 1 THEN Total_Sales ELSE 0 END as Sunday,
    CASE WHEN weekdays = 2 THEN Total_Sales ELSE 0 END as Monday,
    CASE WHEN weekdays = 3 THEN Total_Sales ELSE 0 END as Tuesday,
    CASE WHEN weekdays = 4 THEN Total_Sales ELSE 0 END as Wednesday,
    CASE WHEN weekdays = 5 THEN Total_Sales ELSE 0 END as Thursday,
    CASE WHEN weekdays = 6 THEN Total_Sales ELSE 0 END as Friday,
    CASE WHEN weekdays = 7 THEN Total_Sales ELSE 0 END as Saturday
FROM
    (SELECT 
         DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date) AS Weekdays,
         SUM(sales) AS Total_Sales
     FROM Sales
     WHERE CAST(Date AS date) BETWEEN '2023-03-01' AND '2023-03-10'
     GROUP BY DATEPART(weekday, Date)) X
```

Current result:

| Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| 0.00 | 6.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 38.92 | 0.00 |
| 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 40.55 |

Desired:

| Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 13.84 | 0.00 |
| 0.00 | 6.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 25.08 | 0.00 |
| 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 40.55 |

Dbfiddle example: https://dbfiddle.uk/r-Qg8JDT

Comment: does the row represent the week of the month?

Comment: It does, the main issue i have right now, since someone answered already is getting the results order by the actual date and not the day of the week

Comment: i asked because your sample only have like 2 weeks worth of sample data, i wondered why the desired output has 4..

Comment: i tested it, and it didn't worked, what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN weekdays = 1 THEN total_quantity ELSE 0 END as Sunday,
    CASE WHEN weekdays = 2 THEN total_quantity ELSE 0 END as Monday,
    CASE WHEN weekdays = 3 THEN total_quantity ELSE 0 END as Tuesday,
    CASE WHEN weekdays = 4 THEN total_quantity ELSE 0 END as Wednesday,
    CASE WHEN weekdays = 5 THEN total_quantity ELSE 0 END as Thursday,
    CASE WHEN weekdays = 6 THEN total_quantity ELSE 0 END as Friday,
    CASE WHEN weekdays = 7 THEN total_quantity ELSE 0 END as Saturday
FROM(
 SELECT 
    datepart(WEEKDAY, date) as weekdays,
    SUM(sales) as total_quantity
FROM sales
where cast(date as date)between '2023-03-01' and '2023-03-30'
group by datepart(dayofyear, date), datepart(weekday,date))X
```

It seems to be ok  for that friday.

Dbfiddle example: https://dbfiddle.uk/MbCfqFVY

Comment: is there a way to order the sales by date? the query seems to be ordering by the weekdays instead of the actual date of the total sales

Comment: An `order by` clause? At the moment it's random.

Comment: You can add ```cast(date as date)``` as date_without_timestamp column in subquery and order outer query by that column.

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/pRG3WkIz (you don't need to include date_without_timestamp column in outer query to sort it's for example purpose).

Comment: Bagus Tesa pointed out what would happen if we add one more row on the same day, and it actually failed, not showing for example a value added on 03-31-2023, what am i missing?

Comment: I think ```where cast(date as date)between '2023-03-01' and '2023-03-30'``` included in query can cause that issue.
You simply filter out values after 03-30-2023.

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/h0UcGOx_

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, i forgot that i was using a month with only 30 days earlier, my bad.